# Django countries full name value

Tags: django

Is there a way to get the full name of country in the database using Django-countries. 
My dropdown list shows the full country names but when submitted the country abbreviations are the values that appear in my database. Is there an argument to put in my model? I can’t find an example that shows this.

```
country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want the full country names in your database? It is more efficient to just store the country codes. You could access the full country name through `country.name`.

Comment: To add to the previous comment: No there isn't. That's the whole point of `CountryField`, store the country efficiently using ISO standard codes and being able to get the country name easily in our python code.

Comment: How would that translate in my views ? I’m looking to render a list of all countries on a HTML page

Comment: this worked    {% for user in users %}
        <h2>{{ user.Country.name }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}

Comment: @wpnewbie This helped me with the same issue - I see other examples around but none as simple as your solution, nice one thanks

Comment: @rob
Thanks for your response. Forgot to add as a solution post. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to solve this:

```
{% for user in users %} <h2>{{ user.Country.name }}</h2> {% endfor %}
```